# Saber cual parametro de if se esta tomando para entrar a la condicion?

Tags: javascript, condiciones

tengo una duda, estoy programando en javascript y me gustaria saber si hay alguna forma de saber cual parametro es el que se cumple en un if teniendo varios parametros, es decir

```
if( a>0 || b>0){
 aqui quiero imprimir el que se cumpla de las dos condiciones, es decir si se cumple el primero, que me impima a y si se cumple b entonces que se imprima b}
```

Se que lo puedo hacer mediante else if() o en un case, pero queria saber si hay alguna forma de hacerlo con un solo if, muchas gracias!

Comment: Puedes poner un `alert` con el valor de `a` ó `b` en el cuerpo del `if` para validar cual es el que cumple la condición, igual puede darse que sean ambos.

Comment: Podrias separar en dos ifs

Comment: ¿Que debería pasar si se cumplen ambos? Es decir, `a > 0 && b > 0`, ¿cual sería el resultado correcto?

Comment: En el momento en que se cumpla que a > 0 ya no se analiza la siguiente condicion, por tanto si a > 0 y b> 0 imprimiria solamente a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que confunde un poco es tu comparación, pero lo que intentas lo podrías aproximar usando lo que se conoce como asignación lógica. Digo aproximar, porque tu comparación tiene una ambigüedad.

Los operadores [`&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Operadores_l%C3%B3gicos#AND_()_l%C3%B3gico) (`AND` lógico) y [`||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Operadores_l%C3%B3gicos#OR_()_l%C3%B3gico) (`OR` lógico), al contrario de lo que se piensa (no devuelven `true` o `false`), devuelven el valor de uno de los operandos de acuerdo a una lógica de la implementación del lenguaje.

Por ejemplo:

```js
// usando AND
console.log(true && 5); // devuelve 5
console.log(false && true); // devuelve false
console.log(true && false); // devuelve false
// usando OR
console.log(false || 'Hola mundo'); // devuelve 'Hola mundo'
console.log('3' || false); // devuelve '3'
console.log(true || 'pwnaz'); // devuelve true
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top:0;
}
```

**¿Qué significa esto?**

Sucede que estas expresiones son evaluadas contra [corto-circuitos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Operadores_l%C3%B3gicos#Evaluaci%C3%B3n_contra_corto_circuitos). Dado que los operandos son evaluados de izquierda a derecha, en el caso de la segunda línea anterior (usando `&&`), el primer valor es `false`. Y como se establece para el operador lógico `&&`, no se evalúa el segundo valor, sino que simplemente se devuelve el valor del primer operando (en este caso `false`). En la siguiente línea el primer operando es `true`, por lo tanto se devuelve el valor del segundo operando, que en este caso es `false`. Es exactamente lo que sucede en la evaluación de la primera línea y en este caso se devuelve el valor del segundo operando (el número 5).

Sabiendo esto, podríamos usarlo para almacenar una variable que nos indique cuál valor se ha tomado para la comparación que pretendes (aunque haya una ambigüedad).

**POSIBLE SOLUCIÓN**

La comparación planteada en la pregunta indica que debemos entrar al bloque `if` cuando una de las 2 siguientes condiciones se cumplan:

- `a` es mayor que 0
- `b` es mayor que 0

Como ya vimos que el operador `||` es un operador de corto-circuito, sabemos que el orden en el que planteo la condición afectará al resultado. Si planteo mi cortocircuito de la siguiente forma:

```
a > 0 || b > 0
```

estaré obteniendo la siguiente tabla:

- Si `a` es mayor que cero no seguirá analizando `b`, he entrado a la condición por causa exclusiva de `a`, no importa lo que evalúe `b`.
- Si `a` no es mayor que cero y `b` sí lo es, entonces se entrará en la condición por causa exclusiva de `b`.
- Si `a` y `b` no son mayores que cero, no se entra en la condición.

Es precisamente la ambigüedad del primer punto la que tal vez no podamos salvar, a menos que  estemos conscientes de esto.

Una implementación combinando asignación de variables y el operador lógico `&&`, podría ser la siguiente:

```js
let a, b;
let compare;
// caso: a > 0, b <= 0
a = 3;
b = -1
if(compare = (a > 0 && 'a') || (b > 0 && 'b')) {
  console.log(`He entrado por causa de '${compare}'`);
}

// caso: a > 0, b > 0
a = 3;
b = 1
if(compare = (a > 0 && 'a') || (b > 0 && 'b')) {
  console.log(`He entrado por causa de '${compare}'`);
}

// caso: a <= 0, b > 0
a = -3;
b = 1
if(compare = (a > 0 && 'a') || (b > 0 && 'b')) {
  console.log(`He entrado por causa de '${compare}'`);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Este ejemplo nos muestra claramente la ambigüedad de tu comparación, no por la lógica empleada, sino por las características del lenguaje. Y es que aunque `b` sea mayor que cero, esto no se evalúa y el valor de `compare` será la cadena 'a'.

Analicemos un poco el código:

- `a > 0 && 'a'`, como recordaremos es una expresión lógica de corto-circuito, primero se evalúa el operando `a > 0` si el mismo es `true` o es un valor que [evalúa a `true`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Truthy), entonces se devuelve el segundo operando, que en este caso es la cadena 'a'. Por lo tanto nuestro primer operando toma el valor de 'a' cuando `a > 0`. Y devuelve el resultado de la comparación `a > 0` (`false`) cuando 'a' es menor o igual que cero.

Lo mismo ocurre con nuestro segundo operando, pero el mismo sólo será evaluado si el primer operando devuelve `false`.

**CONCLUSIÓN**

Si bien esto podría darte una pista de cómo *saber* por causa de qué variable he entrado en mi condición, me parece que lo que deberías es replantear tu lógica. Ya que tienes el problema de saber si ambas condiciones se cumplen a la vez. Esto podrías lograrlo haciendo aún más compleja tu sentencia de decisión, pero ya tienes las herramientas necesarias para lograr el cometido. En uno de tus [comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/367985/saber-cual-parametro-de-if-se-esta-tomando-para-entrar-a-la-condicion#comment660289_367987) planteas la posibilidad de identificar cuál se cumplía teniendo varios `||`. La respuesta es que se entrará en la condición por causa del primer operando que evalúe a `true` en una cadena de operadores lógicos:

```
operando1 || operando2 || operando3 || ... || operandoN
```

Por ejemplo:

```js
let a = b = c = d = false;
let e = f = g = true;
let compare;

if(
  compare = (a && 'a') || 
            (b && 'b') ||
            (c && 'c') ||
            (d && 'd') ||
            (e && 'e') ||
            (f && 'f') ||
            (g && 'g') ) {
  console.log(`He entrado por causa de '${compare}'`);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Esto devolverá el primer operando que evalúe a `true`, obviando el resto que quede en la cadena.

Espero que esto te ayude a aclarar el panorama y puedas establecer mejor tu lógica de comparación.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, tu explicación es increible, ya tenia la idea que haciéndolo de la forma en que plantee iba a ser complicado, aun que claro, siempre hay mas opciones en el lenguaje para poder hacerlo y sin duda me ayudaste demasiado a comprender varias situaciones con el if

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres que se imprima el primero si el primero se cumple o el segundo si el segundo se cumple, de una forma simple, podrías usar un [operador ternario](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Conditional_Operator):

```js
let a = 1;
let b = 0;

console.log(a > 0 ? a : (b > 0 ? b : ""));
```

Comment: Entonces, eso seria como hacer if anidados creo yo, en especifico buscaba como identificar cual se cumplia teniendo varios || en un solo if, pero muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer una comparación `ternaria`, funciona igual que el `if`, pero su sintaxis es más parecida a una pregunta "cotidiana", algo así:

```js
var a = 0;
var b = 1;

a == 0 && b==0 ? (alert("ambos son igual a 0")):a == 0 ? (alert("a es igual a 0")) : b == 0 ?(alert('b es igual a 0')):(alert('Ninguno es igual a 0'));
```

Según la condición que se cumpla puedes definir que hacer o mostrar. Espero te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: Entiendo, al parecer me funcionaria algo asi, pero seria como tener if anidados, yo pensaba mas en un solo if y de ahi saber cual es el que se cumple, por ejemplo como en los eventos, que puedes saber cual evento ejecuto cierta funcion, igual muchas gracias!!